# How do I show $x^3 - 9$ is reducible or irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ without checking all 11 cases

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

How do I show $x^3 - 9$ is reducible or irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$. Please explain the thought process.

Thanks

Comment: The question as it stands lacks context: why are you looking at whether that polynomial is irreducible? Why do you not just want to check 11 cases, which seems quite easy to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $$4^3\equiv 9\ (\ mod\ 11\ )$$

You can get this by noting that $2^{10}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 11)$ (Fermat's little
theorem) and therefore $2^{12}=4^6\equiv 4\ ( mod \ 11\ )$. So, $4^3$ is either
$2$ or $9$ modulo $11$, so a candidate to satisfy the congruence.

Comment: So would that tell us that (x- 4) divides x^3 - 9 therefore it is reducible ?

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Answer (score 7):

One can show that $x^3-9\equiv 0\pmod{11}$ has a solution without checking any cases.

For $11$ is prime, and $3$ is relatively prime to $\varphi(11)$. It follows that $f(x)=x^3$ is a one to one mapping from non-zero residue classes modulo $11$ to themselves.

Thus for any $a$, the congruence $x^3\equiv a\pmod{11}$ has a solution.
It follows that $x^3-a$ is reducible modulo $11$ for every $a$, and in particular when $a=9$.

Comment: how does it follows that f(x) = x^3 is a one to one mapping?